# Updates all the indexes with same values except the 0th element

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVb0p.png)
what should I do for the array to hold correct data rather than the duplicates?

for example:
if the array input is [1,2,3,4], instead i would have the output as [1,4,4,4] at the end of the loop.

I want the output as [1,2,3,4]

The values in the array are the objects. just used number for understanding.

Here is the code

```
ratio_array = []
$.each(budget_min_max, function(index, item) {
    if (estimated_budget <= item.max && estimated_budget >= item.min) {
     item.some_value = some_value
      return ratio_array.push(item);
    }
  });
```

So if the array length is 4 then, 0th elements holds the correct data but the 1,2 and 3rd array index will hold the data of the array index 3.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Could you edit your question to be easier to read? At the moment, all I see is a bunch of requirements...

Comment: Sorry my first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: No problem, please just give us the input array and the output expected array. Then we will be able to develope the process you need

Comment: @VelantanDSilva take a look at the answer I gave you, it works with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you could just use map() this way:

```
var budget_min_max = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,];
var ratio_array = budget_min_max.map((item,index,arr) => index === 0 ? item : arr[arr.length-1]);
console.log(ratio_array); // [ 1, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8 ]
```